# How to handle multiple tile sizes in WP 7.8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, tiles, windows-phone-7.8

Now that the `7.8 update` is coming to WP7.x devices, how can I handle the `multiple tile sizes` an app can offer?

What changes do I need to do in the `AppManifest`?

The SDK can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474). Please help as I am not able to find a good resource till now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/22/windows-phone-7-8-and-windows-phone-8-live-tile-light-up-for-windows-phone-os-7-1-apps.aspx), it describes the changes, and references a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on how to set that up.

Another option is to use a CodePlex project called [MangoPollo](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/).

> Mangopollo will allow you to easily take advantage of new windows phone tiles (cyclic, flip, iconic) if your application is run from a Windows Phone 7.8 or 8 as well as new launchers if your application is run from a Windows Phone 8 while remaining compatible with windows phone 7.

Comment: MangoPollo is great, it's what I've been using myself for my apps. I strongly recommend it.